# How to replace a list of misspelled words with a list of correct words?

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm trying to figure out how to replace a long list of misspelled words from a list of correct words but not sure how to do it. Please advise if possible. Thank you.

I tried str_replace and gsub but it seems like because I want to implement the changes from a dataframe so it doesn't really work that way.

```
df = tibble(Movie_Name = list("Black Panthet", "Irom Man", "Captain Anerica", "Black Panthers", "Iron Men", "Captain America", "Avangers"))

correct = tibble(correct_movie_name = list("Black Panther", "Iron Man", "Captain American", "Avengers"))
```

I expect the output to be like this:

```
df = tibble(Movie_Name = list("Black Panther", "Iron Man", "Captain America", "Black Panther", "Iron Man", "Captain America", "Avengers"))
```

Comment: Do you have a specific list of possible strings like your movie titles or is this going to be general text?

Comment: I have a long list of words that some of them are misspelled and I'd like to clean it up, so I came up with a list of correct spelling words and would like to see if I can replace any misspelled words in the long list with the one I created.

Comment: You could check out the fuzzyjoin package: https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin#example-of-stringdist_inner_join-correcting-misspellings-against-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on answers by @G5W and avid_useR

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringdist)

Movie_Name = list("Black Panthet", "Irom Man", "Captain Anerica", "Black Panthers", "Iron Men", "Captain America", "Avangers")

correct_movie_name = list("Black Panther", "Iron Man", "Captain America", "Avengers")

New_Movie_name <- lapply(Movie_Name, function(x) {
  lapply(correct_movie_name, function(y) {
    stringdist(x,y)
  }) %>% unlist() %>% which.min() %>% correct_movie_name[[.]]
})

# New_Movie_name is a list of the same length as Movie_Name but with correct movie names based on elements in list correct_movie_name
```

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to use Levenshtein distance, which is available from the `stringdist` package.

```
library(stringdist)

MovieNames   = unlist(df$Movie_Name)
CorrectNames = unlist(correct$correct_movie_name)

for(MN in MovieNames) {
    CMN = which.min(stringdist(CorrectNames,  MN, method = "lv"))
    cat(MN, " should be ",  CorrectNames[CMN], "\n")
}

Black Panthet  should be  Black Panther 
Irom Man  should be  Iron Man 
Captain Anerica  should be  Captain American 
Black Panthers  should be  Black Panther 
Iron Men  should be  Iron Man 
Captain America  should be  Captain American 
Avangers  should be  Avengers
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a perfect solution for this. The best one could do is to calculate some kind of edit distance between `Movie_Name` and `correct_movie_name` and replace with the word from `correct_movie_name` with the smallest distance. What metric to use depends a lot on the situation and there are a lot of tweaking needed. Here I've used the `stringdist` function from the `stringdist` package which has a variety of distance metrics you can choose. The default is the "restricted Damerau-Levenshtein distance" (from `?stringdist`). We can also use `levenshsteinDist` from `RecordLinkage` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringdist)
library(RecordLinkage)

replace_names <- function(vec, replace_list, dist_func){
  map_chr(vec, ~{
    replace_list[which.min(dist_func(.x, replace_list))]
  })
}

df %>%
  mutate(Correct_stringdist = replace_names(Movie_Name, correct$correct_movie_name, stringdist),
         Correct_levenshsteinDist = replace_names(Movie_Name, correct$correct_movie_name, levenshteinDist))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Movie_Name      Correct_stringdist Correct_levenshsteinDist
  <chr>           <chr>              <chr>                   
1 Black Panthet   Black Panther      Black Panther           
2 Irom Man        Iron Man           Iron Man                
3 Captain Anerica Captain American   Captain American        
4 Black Panthers  Black Panther      Black Panther           
5 Iron Men        Iron Man           Iron Man                
6 Captain America Captain American   Captain American        
7 Avangers        Avengers           Avengers
```

Answer (score 0):

The `agrep` function allows you to do approximate matching between strings.

```
df = tibble(Movie_Name = list("Black Panthet", "Irom Man", "Captain Anerican", "Black Panthers", "Iron Men", "Captain America", "Avangers"))

correct = tibble(correct_movie_name = list("Black Panther", "Iron Man", "Captain America", "Avengers"))

df2 = tibble( Movie_Name = sapply(df$Movie_Name, function(x){
                  for(i in correct$correct_movie_name){
                    comparison <- agrep(i, x)
                    if(length(comparison) != 0){
                      if(comparison == 1){
                      return(i)
                    }}
                  }
                  return(x)
                }))
```